# Disable landscape orientation in Android Browser?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, orientation

I know there is a way to restrict the orientation within an app, but is there a way in code of a web page (whether it be `HTML, CSS or JS`) to restrict the web view to only potrait?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Webview inside an Activity you will restrict to portrait adding the property

> android:screenOrientation

to your Manifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="Jorge´s Activity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. That kind of control is on Android's end, not the web page it's displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to show a message telling the user to turn their phone if the orientation is not right. `window.orientation` will tell you the orientation of the device. 0 is upright, 90 is landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```